# Plotting a volatile data file with gnuplot dynamically

Tags: c++, dynamic, plot, gnuplot

I've seen some similar questions out of which I have made a system which works for me but I need to optimize it because this program alone is taking up a lot of CPU load.

Here is the problem exactly.

I have an incoming signal/stream of data which I need to plot in real time. I only want a limited number of points to be displayed at a time (Say 1024 points) so I plot the data points along the y axis against an index from 0-1024 on the x-axis. The values of the incoming data range from 0-1023.

What I do currently (This is all in C++) is I put the data into a circular loop as it comes and each time the data gets updated (Or every second/third data point), I write out to a file and using a pipe, I plot the data from that file with gnuplot.

While this works almost perfectly, it causes a fair bit of load (Depending on the input data rate, I saw even 70% usage on both my cores of my Core 2 Duo). I'll need to be running some processor intensive code along with this short program so I feel that it is almost necessary to optimize it.

What I was hoping could be done is this: Can I only plot the differences between the current plot and the new data (Or plot each point as it comes in without replotting the whole graph such that the old item at that x index is removed).

I have a fixed number of points on the graph so replot wouldn't work. I want the old point at that x location to be removed.

Comment: You are making a system call to call gnuplot? Where's does the output of gnuplot go?  Into a graphic file?

Comment: Downvoter:  Please leave a comment stating exactly **WHY** you downvoted.  How are people supposed to learn if you don't provide feedback?

Comment: @Mark -- Presumably it goes to some terminal (probably x11 or wxt).

Comment: 4 years and 11 months ago this was posted.  And now there is a simple, elegant solution.  See @Pierz's answer and the comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to accomplish can't be done.  You can mark a datafile as `volatile` or use the `refresh` keyword, but those only update the plot without re-reading the data.  You want to re-read the data and then only update the differences.

There are a few things that might be helpful though.  1) your eye can only register ~26 frames per second.  So, if you have a way to make sure that you only send data 26x per second to gnuplot, that might help.  2) How are you writing the datafiles?  Are you dumping as ascii or binary?  Doing a binary dump might be faster (both for writing and for gnuplot to read).  You'll have to experiment.

There is one hack which will probably not make your script go faster, but you can try it (if you know a reasonable yrange to set, and are using points to plot the data)...

```
#set up code:
set style line 1 lc rgb "blue"
set xrange [0:1023]
set yrange [0:1]
plot NaN notitle #Only need to do this once.
for [i=0:1023] set label i+1 at i,0 point ls 1  #Labels must have tags > 0 :-(

#this part gets repeated by your C code.
#you could move a few points at a time to make it more responsive.
set label 401 at 400,0.8              #move point number 400 to a different y value
refresh                               #show it at it's new location.
```

Comment: Currently, I'm dumping the data as ascii. I thought about piping the data directly in the command but I felt that it would not have made any difference.

This hack seems like it might work since I do have a fixed set of data points in a limited y-range. I'll try it in the evening and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: This didn't work. In fact, it actually made it slower. What happens is this: The data is piped to gnuplot as fast as it came. The plotting was very slow (Compared to the earlier version) and was not real time. I issued a printf statement along with the pipe statement. I saw the printf almost lapping the plot and within a couple of seconds after that, it gave a segmentation fault (Most probably because the pipe overflowed with data. I think what this means is that refresh replots the entire set of points and it's slower than plotting directly from a data file.

Comment: With both methods, I'm only replotting every fifth/tenth point. With the original method, you can't tell that it's skipping.

Comment: @AjaykumarKannan -- I didn't expect it to be faster, but I thought I'd suggest it in case it was.  The re-plotting may actually be faster, however, gnuplot can probably parse an input data file a lot faster than it can parse the script being piped in.

Comment: I see. That would explain it. I'll stick with this method itself for now then. If I need to optimize it later on, I'll reduce the plotting frequency. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gnuplot to do dynamic plotting of data as explained in their [FAQ](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~jeffay/dirt/FAQ/gnuplot.html), using the `reread` function. It seems to run at quite a low load and automatically scrolls the graph when it reaches the end. To run at low load I found I had to add a `; sleep 1` after the awk command (in their example file dyn-ping-loop.gp) otherwise it spends too much CPU on looping on the awk processing.

Comment: Here is a Q&A that explains the reread function: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44470965/how-can-you-watch-gnuplot-realtime-data-plots-as-a-live-graph-with-automatic-up - no awk; All done in gnuplot.  Near-real-time live animated graphs using pause and reread.